# Getting instance of content page within the master page

Tags: asp.net

How can I get the instance of the content page from the maste page?

I need it for that:
All my content pages derive from BasePage class (and BasePage derives from System.Web.UI.Page), the BasePage has a property Index.
The derived page set it's value so that master page can read id and apply special CSS to corresponded menu item that is located on the master page.

Answer (score 5):

Just cast the current page from your `MasterPage` as your `BasePage`:

```
BasePage currentPage = (BasePage)this.Page;
int index = currentPage.Index;

SetMenuIndex(index);
```

Comment: but "this" is not ref of the masterpage?

Comment: `Page` is the Page... `this.Page` is the same as `Page`.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as it's correct.  Thanks, GenericTypeTeam, you've just saved me asking pretty much the same question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a public function to change the css in the MasterPage that you can call from derived pages on index change.

```
 DirectCast(Me.Page.Master, YourMasterPageType).ChangeCss()
```